# How to return table from function and execute stored procedure within this function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have function that must return table using `SELECT` then it must call stored procedure to write down to a log.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetEntries 
     (@UPIN VARCHAR(32)) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
    RETURN
        SELECT 
            DocumentNumber, Date, IsValid, ExpireDate, Message 
        FROM 
            ENTRIES 
        WHERE 
            UPIN = @UPIN;

    EXEC WriteToLog @UPIN, 'Accessed Entries', GETDATE;
```

But I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near EXEC

What to do?

Comment: You can't excute an SP in a UDF, except you [cheat](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/8955/how-can-call-stored-procedure-inside-function-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: You can't execute a T-SQL proc from within a function. Functions can only call extended stored procedures. Consider using a proc instead of function to do this.

Comment: @DanGuzman, but I need to return table from SELECT

Comment: Is there some reason you can't you encapsulate the outer SELECT in a proc?

Comment: As sami and dan mentioned you cannot call a stored proc from within a function.  (except with a hack using OPENROWSET or a CLR) but the reality is you should discuss what you want to do as Dan is probably correct that you just need a well written stored procedure and not a function at all?

Comment: "then it must call stored procedure to write down to a log." - if you need to implement an auditing system you should do it using SQL Server's built-in auditing functionality instead of building it into your data-access logic - this is because auditing is a different "aspect" (see: Aspect-Oriented Programming) that will significantly muddy and mess-up your existing codebase, making it unmaintainable.